# jQuery disable click but not link

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I just want to disable the ability for a user to click, with the exception of links

```
$('selector').children().not('a').click(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

this doesn't work..
thanks

Comment: Can you show your markup?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting errors? Is it partially working?

Comment: Disable the ability for users to click what? Buttons? And you're selecting elements called `selector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`children` only selects the immediate children.

To disable all of `selector`'s descendants, use this:

```
$('selector :not(a)').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Or, to be a little more efficient, use delegation:

```
$('selector').on('click', ':not(a)', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to disable the user from clicking stuff other than links, simply do this:

```
$('selector').find(':not(a)').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

It applies to all elements other than links.